# Connecting to db in cordova android app

Tags: javascript, android, html, database, cordova

I'm trying to develop an app using Phonegap.In this app i need to create a simple register form and connect it to db so the user details will be stored in db.But when trying to run the created app i'm getting following errors in LogCat.I have searched for ways to solve it but was unable to get it fixed.

Errors in LogCat:

file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 41 : TypeError: Result of expression 'parentElement' [null] is not an object.

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $ at file:///android_asset/www/Register.html:68

index.js file:

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
 var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
 var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening'); //line 41
 var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);  
      } 
    };
    app.initialize();
```

Line 68 in Register.html is the following code in insertDB(tx) function.

```
    var insertname = $('[name="name"]').val();
```

Code related to the register form.

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1"> 
    <div data-role="header" >
        <h1>Register</h1>

    </div>

   <div data-role="content">
    <form method="get" onsubmit="" >
      <fieldset class="ui-field-contain">

        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" />
        <p>    </p>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" />
        <p>    </p>
        <label for="password">Password </label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" autocomplete="off"/>
       <br />
        <button class="ui-btn-right" onclick='return submitForm()'>Register</button>


        </fieldset>
      </form>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: this error means you havent include the jquery .js script in your html.

Comment: actually i have included..
<script src="../jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 68, can you change it to:

```
var insertname = $('#name').val();
```

or

```
var insertname = document.getElementsByName("name");
```

to get your expected result?

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve :) `var insertname = document.getElementsByName("name");`
worked for me :)